# Within Group Error in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am getting a within group error in PostgreSQL 9.4:

ERROR:  WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate rank
LINE 4:  (select a1.rank as r1,

```
create view a as (select rank() over (order by pid, time)
    pid, event, time
    from test5);



select e1.prev, e1.event, count(*) 
from 
    eventtransitions as e1,
    (select a1.rank as r1,
         a2.rank as r2,
         a1.event as a1_event,
         a2.event as a2_event,
         a1.pid as a1_pid,
         a2.pid as a2_pid
from a as a1, a as a2) as temp
where r1 = r2-1
and e1.event = a2_event
and e1.prev = a1_event
and a1_pid = a2_pid
group by e1.prev, e1.event;
```

Which is a little weird to me because from what I understand about this error, it means that I need to have order by clause for my aggregate function rank. However, I did make the view a and I have order by clause there. How do I fix this error and what assumption am I making that is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is a typo in the view.  I *believe* what you wanted was this:

```
create view a as
select
  rank() over (order by pid, time),
  pid, event, time
from test5;
```

As it stands your current view definition:

```
create view a as (select rank() over (order by pid, time)
    pid, event, time
    from test5);
```

Actually takes the `rank()` function and aliases it as "pid" which is the equivalent of this:

```
create view a as (select rank() over (order by pid, time) as pid,
    event, time
    from test5);
```

As a result, when you call rank in your select query, it is referring to the function, not the field (which doesn't exist, because you aliased it).